# Leading zeroes not working with number data type

Tags: sql, oracle

When I select from a view, the result with preceding zeroes coming again because

of the number data type. I need the result without leading zeroes.

```
 -------CODE----------
create table test_number_type(c1 number);

insert into test_number_type values(100.12);

insert into test_number_type values(0.12);

commit;

create or replace view  test_data_type as
select to_number(trim(leading 0 from c1)) c_num_check from test_number_type;

desc test_data_type
```

---

Comment: You can format a number to control how it is displayed when displaying it :-)

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (Perhaps Oracle ?)

Answer (score 3):

Your concern is entirely misplaced.  Numbers are stored using an *internal* representation.  They are not stored as strings.  So, all these represent the same number (with a caveat that follows):

```
0.12
.12
000000.12
```

The caveat is that the internal representation might differ somewhat in terms of scale and precision.

How the number gets presented is not really up to the column.  If you want to control the output, convert the value to a string.  The function [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm) allows you to control the leading zeros.